# javax.print PrintJobListener printJobCompleted or printJobFailed events never called

Tags: java, printing

I am using `javax.print.PrintJobListener` to monitor printer job status, but regardless of print success I never get `printJobCompleted` or `printJobFailed/printJobCanceled` events. 
I always get `printDataTransferCompleted` and `printJobNoMoreEvents` events but I from that I can not know if document is really printed or not.

There is a suggestion [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/558198/java/java/PrintJobListener-working-properly) to check `PrintService` attributes on `printJobNoMoreEvents` event and see if print queue is empty, but it also doesn't work because attributes are not updated immediatelly, so even if print succeeded it says it has 1 job in queue, which is also case if printing fails.

Any experiences with this, anyone? Is this `javax.print` problem , or maybe specific printer problem? I am using `Epson TM-T88V` printer on linux (downloaded driver from epson site). I get same behavior on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Anand , unfortunately no. Even on www.experts-exchange.com nobody couldn't offer a solution for this. Seem like it just doesn't work with some printer models.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my post and let me know if you also faced the same situations? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31445192/3017645

Answer (score 0):

`javax.print` totally depends on the system's print system. On Linux and OS X the implementation of `javax.print` probably uses command line tools to communicate with CUPS. CUPS on the other hand depends on the driver for your specific printer. It is not unusual that detailed status information is not available or not forwarded by one of the many components involved. Simple Drivers just "fire & forget".

In case your printer supports IPP you can read the attribute `job-state` from the IPP Job Object. These available IPP implementations might help: cups4j or jspi.